# Explanation of `< /dev/urandom tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9`

Tags: bash

In [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/30184/10-ways-to-generate-a-random-password-from-the-command-line/) article, I came across the following command:

```
< /dev/urandom tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9 | head -c${1:-32}
```

I haven't seen this kind of expression in Bash yet. Specifically, the `<` at the start and the concatenation of `/dev/urandom` and `tr` surprised me. As far as I interpret this command, we're reading data from `/dev/urandom` into the `tr` command, but why is the `< /dev/urandom` first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirection operators can be placed anywhere in a simple command (see [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/86440) — “simple” is in the POSIX sense here, as opposed to compound).

Placing the input redirection first helps make the data flow clearer: reading from left to right, data is read from `/dev/urandom`, processed by `tr`, then piped to `head`.

Reading

```
tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9 < /dev/urandom | head -c${1:-32}
```

instead means not knowing where `tr` gets its data from until after its arguments; there aren’t many here, but with more complex commands it can make quite a difference.

Comment: This explanation seems logical, but I regard the redirection operators as arrows explicitly depicting the data flow. If we put it first, it looks like the data flows "out" of the command, which confused me, while when we put it after the `tr`, we can directly see, the random numbers flow into `tr`.